# What is the name / term of this symbol, half tick half cross

Tags: names

My teachers sometimes put this symbol in my homework.
Does it have a name or term in English?

[image]

Comment: I (a native US English speaker) actually don't think I've ever seen this before.  Are your teachers from an English-speaking country?  It might just not be common here.

Comment: Google Image search also doesn't return any valid result. Check the [Checkmark with cross](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/202732)

Comment: Do your teachers put other symbols on your homework, such as a plain tick or a plain cross, that might throw some light on this combination?

Comment: Do you know what your teachers mean by it? I have seen this sort of thing before (native British), but only when a teacher has changed their mind/realised they had marked something as correct when it wasn't/realised someone else's marking was wrong. As far as I know, it doesn't have a name.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. The English teachers who put that symbol in my homework are from South Korea. I don't know korean language, so I am wondering if that is a korean character and if it carries some special meaning. Sometimes, I am so afraid to ask questions in their classes, because I have never seen them smile.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, while it was asked in good faith, it does not in fact appear to have any standard meaning in English.

Comment: @SteveES: Also British (Scotland), and I've seen lecturers use it to show that the working was correct but the answer was wrong (since here, at least, you're awarded marks for correct working irrespective of the answer). Also, where a previous incorrect answer has been used with correct working and the error propagated.